# iOS App: Resizing Image after Orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm going to apologize in advance as I'm sure my answer is out there, but after trying many suggestions, I just can't seem to get my app to work correctly.

Basically, I want to display a 16x9 image in the same scale to the full width of the screen staying in the center of the screen.  The image will be larger in landscape orientation as compared to portrait orientation.  I can display the image but when my Ipad is rotated to portrait, it clips the sides of the image keeping the image the original height.  I am not using the layout editor and would prefer not to for my first app.  The image is loaded using the below code.

viewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView* MobileImage;  // image on mobile device
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView* MobileImage;
@end
```

viewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize MobileImage;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = width * 9 / 16;
    if (height > self.view.bounds.size.height) {  // just in case
        height = self.view.bounds.size.height;
        width = height * 16 / 9;
    }
    self.MobileImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height)];
    self.MobileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sandy-ralph" ofType:@"png"]];
    self.MobileImage.center = self.view.center;
    self.MobileImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    self.MobileImage.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:self.MobileImage];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

This works fine if I don't care about the clipping (assuming I started in landscape and rotate to portrait).  I insert the below code into the viewController implementation in my attempt to resize it:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    NSLog(@"Transition to size = %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));
    CGFloat width = size.width;
    CGFloat height = width * 9 / 16;
    if (height > size.height) {  // just in case
        height = size.height;
        width = height * 16 / 9;
    }

#if 1  // this code has no effect on the image size
    NSLog(@"Using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext");
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    [self.MobileImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
    UIImage *newimage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSUInteger i1 = [self.view.subviews indexOfObject:self.MobileImage];
    UIView *superview = self.MobileImage.superview;
    [self.MobileImage removeFromSuperview];
    self.MobileImage.image = newimage;
    [superview insertSubview:self.MobileImage atIndex:i1];
#else  // the code resizes but causes image to sit on bottom of screen
    NSLog(@"Using CGRectMake");
    self.MobileImage.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height);
#if 1  // With/without next three lines, image still sits on bottom of screen
    self.MobileImage.center = CGPointMake(width / 2, height / 2);
    self.MobileImage.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
    self.MobileImage.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
#endif
#endif
}
```

The preprocessor directives are for testing different code.  With "#if 1", there is no resizing.  With "#if 0", it resizes, but is positioned at the bottom with/without the code to center it.  I assume it is a small fix, but I've been trial and testing, for way longer than my wife will tolerate (ie. ignoring the "to do list"), with no progress and I thought it was time to seek help.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

To get new width and height use this:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    CGFloat screenWidth = size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = size.height;


    UIImage* image = self.MobileImage.image;
    CGFloat mobileImageWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat mobileImageHeight = image.size.height;

    CGFloat newMobileImageWidth = 0;
    CGFloat newMobileImageHeight = 0;

    double widthRatio = mobileImageWidth / screenWidth;
    double heightRatio = mobileImageHeight / screenHeight;

    if (widthRatio < heightRatio) {
        newMobileImageHeight = screenHeight;
        newMobileImageWidth = screenWidth / widthRatio;
    }
    else {
        newMobileImageWidth = screenWidth;
        newMobileImageHeight = screenHeight / heightRatio;
    }

    //use these new width and height for your image

}
```

Comment: I already had the new width and height calculated in the variables of the same name and the image is correctly resized to those values with the code:     self.MobileImage.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height);
It's what to do with the new width and height that I'm stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out what I needed to make it work.  Not sure if it is the best way, but it's good enough for my test program.  Also, no longer need the autoresizing as well.  In case someone else has the same problem, the code now looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat viewheight = self.view.bounds.size.height - [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
    CGFloat width = self.view.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat height = width * 9 / 16;
    if (height > viewheight) {  // don't exceed viewable height
        height = viewheight;
        width = height * 16 / 9;
    }
    self.MobileImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, width, height)];
    self.MobileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sandy-ralph" ofType:@"png"]];
    self.MobileImage.center = self.view.center;

    [self.view addSubview:MobileImage];
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    CGFloat statusbarheight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height;
    CGFloat viewheight = size.height - statusbarheight;
    CGFloat width = size.width;
    CGFloat height = width * 9 / 16;
    if (height > viewheight) {  // don't exceed viewable height
        height = viewheight;
        width = height * 16 / 9;
    }

    CGRect frame = self.MobileImage.frame;
    frame.size.width = width;
    frame.size.height = height;
    frame.origin.x = (size.width - width) / 2;
    frame.origin.y = statusbarheight + (viewheight - height) / 2;
    self.MobileImage.frame = frame;
}
```